# Building Tensorflow 1.4.0 from sources for C/C++ in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, ubuntu, tensorflow

I am trying to build Tensorflow 1.4.0 from sources for C/C++ in 64-bit Ubuntu 17.10. I tried to follow the instructions in [Tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) and [other website for C++](http://www.blitzblit.com/2017/06/11/creating-tensorflow-c-headers-and-libraries/) using Bazel and summarize them as follows:

```
cd tensorflow
./configure
(select N for all the options)
bazel build --config=opt --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" --local_resources 2048,.5,1.0 //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so //tensorflow:libtensorflow_framework.so //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg
sudo -H pip3 install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.4.0rc1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

When I tried to build a simple test program and include *tensorflow/core/public/session.h* in Eclipse (with the include path set to the tensorflow root folder downloaded from git), it complained several things:

1. Missing Google's protobuf common.h in *device_attributes.pb.h* (I cannot use *apt-get* to install protobuf as it will complain version too old - lower than 3.0.0.4 check in *device_attributes.pb.h*). I downloaded the latest protobuf and follow the instructions to install it
2. Missing Eigen3's Tensor file in *tensor.h*, where tensor.h includes Tensor file in *[tensorflow directory]/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor*, and *[tensorflow directory]/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor* includes the missing *[/usr/include/eigen3/]unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor* file provided by libeigen3-dev. I *apt-get* to install libeigen3-dev.
3. After I installed libeigen3-dev, I added */usr/include/eigen3* to the Eclipse's include path as the Tensor file in tensorflow directory is unable to find the Tensor file in */usr/include* (with extra eigen3 directory).
4. Missing *nsync_cv.h* file in *mutex.h*. I added nsync folder in tensorflow directory to the include path.

In summary, I have added the following paths to the include path in Eclipse:

- [tensorflow directory]/
- [tensorflow directory]/bazel-genfiles
- [tensorflow directory]/bazel-tensorflow/external/nsync/public
- /usr/include/eigen3

I added the library path *[tensorflow directory]/bazel-bin/tensorflow* with the following libraries:

- tensorflow
- tensorflow_cc
- tensorflow_framework

I have also added *-std=c++11* to the GCC C++ compiler and GCC C++ Linker in the Eclipse's project settings. In the end it encountered a linker error:

```
[tensorflow directory]/tensorflow/core/platform/default/logging.h:187: undefined reference to `tensorflow::internal::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString[abi::cxx11]()'
```

I have seen a [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5179) discussing similar issue but I did set `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` and Ubuntu 17.10 is using gcc5 or above.

Please kindly suggest how to fix the linker error. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially, you have to create your C++ project in tensorflow sourcetree, write BUILD file and compile it using bazel. Look at [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image).

I wrote a blog post: https://tuanphuc.github.io/standalone-tensorflow-cpp/ giving detailed instructions to make a standalone C++ Tensorflow with configuration:

  `-  Ubuntu 17.10
  -  gcc 7.2.0
  -  tensorflow 1.4.0
  -  Python 2 or 3
  -  cmake 3.9.6
  -  Eigen 3.3.4
  -  Protobuf (master branch)
  -  Googletest (master branch)
  -  bazel`

Hope it helps

References:

[Packaged TensorFlow C++ library for bazel-independent use](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2412)

[graph.pb.h missing](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1890)

Comment: I made several adjustments to to be able to compile it (e.g. Makefile to add /usr/include/eigen3 and ltensorflow_framework, install latest protobuf using configure/make/make install). Unfortunately I still got the same the linker error i.e. tensorflow/core/platform/default/logging.h:187: undefined reference to `tensorflow::internal::CheckOpMessageBuilder::NewString[abi:cxx11]()'

Comment: I cloned 1.4.0 and did all the step above and it worked. Do you correctly copy the /libtensorflow_cc.so:
`cp -r $TENSORFLOW_DIR/bazel-bin/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so ./lib/`
In fact, you don't need to add  /usr/include/eigen3 because it is already in include/third_party/. Which version of protobuf that you use ? I use 3.3.2

Comment: I did copy libtensorflow_cc.so correctly. I tried to search the _Tensor_ file and it only has 1 hit which is located at [tensorflow directory]/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor which `#include "unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"`. Please can you confirm you have two Tensor files in the tensorflow directory? I am using the latest protobuf v3.4 in the master branch.

Comment: I have only one Tensor also

Comment: So do you have Tensor file in your /usr/include or /usr/local/include?

Comment: No I don't. I didn't copy any header files of tensorflow into /usr/local/include. As I said in the instruction, I create a new folder name toucango_cpp (ex: /home/user/toucango_cpp). Then all necessary files are copied into toucango_cpp/include as in my instructions so Tensor file is in toucango_cpp/include/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor

Comment: The very first line of the Tensor file in the tensorflow directory is `#include "unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"` and there are few ifdef but other than that nothing else (15 lines in total). The Tensor file in /usr/include I installed has 152 lines and the first line of the code is `#include "../../../Eigen/Core"`. Which one do you have?

Comment: I have the 15-line one. Where the 152-line one comes from ?

Comment: The 152-line one comes from the official Eigen library, in fact you don't need it because it is in toucango_cpp/include/third_party/eigen3. So I guess you just remove /usr/include/eigen3 in your Makefile  (or use my Makefile) and recompile

Comment: So you are saying after you have built the tensorflow from sources you have two files in tensorflow directory before you copy them to your own include folder, so where are they? I only have one file in [tensorflow directory]/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor (15-line one). I did not have a Makefile to build the official Eigen library. I `apt-get install libeigen3-dev` simply because I only have one file (15-line one) when I first build it (that's not the case where I had libeigen3-dev installed and tensorflow build won't install it because it already exists).

Comment: Also may I know what is your Linux distro and gcc version? It looks to me that the linker error is nothing to do with Eigen library. However for some reason this is to do with CXX11 and protobuf mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5179). How did you install protobuf (`yum` or `ap-get`, or download yourself and build it)?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 16.04 and gcc 5.4.0. 

I have two Tensor files: one in `/usr/local/include/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/` when I installed Eigen from source, and one in `[tensorflow directory]/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor`

However, I didn't used Eigen in /usr/local/include, I used eigen copied from tensorflow directory instead so no need to install official Eigen to compile.

I used Ubuntu 16.04, gcc 5.4.0 and protobuf 3.3.2 installed from sources.

Comment: I don't think it will compile. If you open the file `[tensorflow directory]/third_party/eigen3/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor` (15-line one) you will see `#include "unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor"` (152-line one). If you do not have the Tensor file (152-line one) it should flag a compilation error.

Comment: Few more questions, when you download the tensorflow 1.4.0, you need to do configure before running bazel build. Did you specify any configure option? Which python version do you use (to point to python or python3)? Did you set all other options to N?

Comment: I did configure for python and used all default parameters

Comment: So which python version you use: python2 or python3?

Comment: It's python2, sorry. You use which python ?

Comment: I will try to make a docker this weekend.

Comment: Nice to see it helps you out :) Sorry for the first answer that caused confusions :)

Comment: Many thanks. By the way I found out the culprit of the linker error comes from the additional option in bazel-build `--cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"` which is recommended by tensorflow website for gcc 5 or above. If I remove this option, everything builds fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to tinker with your environment too much there are two unofficial alternatives. One is to compile the C++ API with Floop's [tensorflow_cc](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc) project and install on your system. The other possibility is to install one of the [releases](https://github.com/kecsap/tensorflow_cpp_packaging/releases) of my packaging project for C and C++ API of Tensorflow. Both projects use CMake (instead of Bazel) to support C++ compilation of your source files.

From Tensorflow point of view, the advantage of tensorflow_cc that you can build GPU support if you want while my project can only use CPU for inference.